# Why is svelecte creating [object Object] when I create a new item?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, selectize.js, selectinput

In my SvelteKit project I am using the [svelecte](https://github.com/mskocik/svelecte) package to add selectize-style select inputs. The initial values are passed in via the the `data` variable created by svelte's `load` function when the page is requested.

```
<Svelecte id="category" 
    options={categories} 
    creatable = true
    on:createoption={newCategory}
    bind:value={selected}
    on:change="{do_something}">
 </Svelecte>
```

Within my `<script>` tag in the corresponding `+page.svelte` file I have:

```
let categories = data.categories;
let selected;

function newCategory(c) {
  categories.push(c.detail.value);
}
```

This works fine except when I try to create a new item. The new Item I create appears in the input, but then when I try to change my selection, instead of the item I created, the new option is shown as [object Object]

[image: svelecte options after new item added]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can log `c.detail.value` and compare it against `categories[0]` to see if anything fishy there.

Comment: Thanks @hackape. They are the same, but your comment made me think a little more about the form the options should actually take leading to the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, it occurred to me that svelecte is creating an object when I add a new item. Re-reading the docs I see that the values should be in the form of `{value: value, label: label}`. It through me off that just providing an array of values worked for initially creating the input. So the following change fixes it for me:

```
- let categories = data.categories;
+ let categories = data.categories.map(function(c) { return({value: c, label:c}) });
```